# Azure service for time-series metric gathering and analytics

Tags: cloud-service

I'm looking to log non-browser events and run aggregation/analytics on Microsoft Azure (something similar to Google Analytics's Measurement Protocol):

- Ability to send preformed packets (prefer UDP, but TCP or HTTP GET/POST is okay) from any backend (NOT limited to the browser!)
- Automatic, unlimited storage of data (random sampling is okay for very large data groups)
- Robust, multi-dimensional analytics across custom time-ranges
- Data points will be events, such as "Feature A activated with sub-values A1:5, A2:7"
- Looking for a **paid** product within Microsoft's Azure umbrella

Comment: Please rewrite your question without mentioning GA. That will force you to exactly describe what you need, thus making your question better. Thanks!

Comment: Done, please review and ungate.

Comment: "within Microsoft's Azure umbrella": Is it absolutely required?

Comment: Yes, I have monthly usage credits with Azure.